# Data validation dropdown list selected item auto update when source list changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets. One sheet where I define category of items. Like

```
Category
<big>
<small>
<cute>
```

In other sheet I have list of items, where I'm assigning prepared category via data validation dropdown list.

```
item1  <big>
item2  <small>
item3  <cute>
```

I created data validation using Data->validation and picked data range and list range.

**But when I change  to , the change doesn't populate into other sheet.** It only shows warning, that cell contain invalid data.

It is possible to update (automatically or by some script) selected item in dropdown menu, when I change it's source data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is more a Google Spreadsheet related question but when you change value of a category exemple  to  the change will  not be populated to previously selected values, it is normal. It is the way spreadsheet and excel works.

The way to automate change is to build a script which will replace values. My favorite solution is more to use replace function (ctrl+H). It is built in spreadsheet :-)

Other solution there is an addon : [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-find-and-replace/gdjlbafkoaciknlpkmiedbgnlfglcpmb)

Stéphane